# Is there a way to improve the number of equation available in graph mode on a casio graph calculator?

Tags: calculator

I am searching a way to improve my graph 90+e casio calculator.
I like to draw things with the graph mode and I recently found myself limited by the number of 20 equations slots available.
I would like to find a way to increase the number of equation slots available.
The file that handles the graphic mode is a .g3m file. It works in Casio BASIC, but I don't know how casio BASIC works.
I really need help
thanks in advance for answers